# Why MongoDB $expr makes query valid

Tags: mongodb

I am using Metabase, which uses MongoDB. There is a custom aggregation to be done. So I tried to create simple aggregate query that queries data that were created in last 90 days.

**Problem:**

I found our 2 ways how it could be done. However one returns needed data, one does not. It seems, both queries are doing the very same thing. Can anyone explain in more detail **HOW** the second approach is different?

**First query that returns records:**

```js
db.records.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "$expr": {
                "$gte": [
                    "$createdAt", { "$subtract": [ISODate(), { "$multiply": [3600000, 24, 90] }] }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Second query that returns no records:**

```js
db.records.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "createdAt": {
                "$gte": {
                    "$subtract": [ISODate(), { "$multiply": [3600000, 24, 90] }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Note:** By query being invalid, means query runs, however no records have been returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's how it works, if you want to use `$subtract` in a `$match`, it must be in a `$expr`.

From the docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/

> `$match` takes a document that specifies the query conditions. The query syntax is identical to the read operation query syntax; i.e. `$match` does not accept raw aggregation expressions. Instead, use a `$expr` query expression to include aggregation expression in `$match`.